# Error Messages while doing assembleRelease in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

From the gradle script on right of the Android Studio when I click it I recieve Red mark on Configure Build , But I see in the Gradle Console Window and the EventLog Windows there is no Error Message.

[image: AssembelRelease]

[image: Assemble-release-on-gradle]

How will I come to know what is causing this?Also my rebuild works fine with no errors.

Comment: please add the error log.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך Thats what the Question is .Where to get the error logs?

Comment: on log cat or message perhaps? http://imgur.com/a/R8WpU